# Overflow hidden breaks layout

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons and one of them contains input file. I added `overflow: hidden` to it in order to keep size of the button. Unfortunately this broke the line of buttons. Does anybody have idea how to fix that: http://jsfiddle.net/HNx8f/1/

Comment: Removing the `overflow: hidden` seems to work nicely. It doesn't change the button's size. What are you seeing that doesn't work when you remove `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/HNx8f/3/ ?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` cut internal input so I can click only inside of the button. Just add different color for buttons on hover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `vertical-align:bottom;` to the `.bottom` class and the buttons will appear inline again.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HNx8f/4/

```
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Check out [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) for a full list of the properties you may use, however in your case any of these should help you:

- top
- middle
- bottom

Answer (score 0):

Modifing the class .bottom will solve the issue

```
.button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    border: 0 none;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: I you wish to use `float:left` then there's no need to have `display:inline-block` therefore I would recommend removing that attribute altogether.  Secondly if using `float` there needs to be `clear:both` added to the following element to prevent that element also appearing inline.  Alternatively you could add the clear to a pseudo class of `.button`.

Comment: when I put float:left and add margin then it displays correctly thats why didnt noticed the presence of display:inline-block thanks for notifying me